# fkCalculated (TField) вычислить разность смежных значений поля

Tags: база-данных, delphi, firebird, interbase

Доброе время суток,
Есть *DataSet*, в нем поле *Field1*

```
Id Field1
1     20
2     25
3     36
4     47
```

Вопрос:
Можно каким-либо образом, используя вычисляемое поле, получить в нем разность смежных значений поля *Field1* (именно в *DataSet*, не в запросе), т.е получить результат:

```
id Field1  FieldCalc
1     20
2     25       5
3     36       11
4     47       11
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Или всеже *fkData* и перебором строк *DataSet*, вставлять результрат в *FieldCalc*?

Answer (score 2):

Ну, чтобы вычисляемое поле вычислялось, все равно необходимо определить у `DataSet` событие `OnCalFields` и описывать там алгоритм вычисления. Значит можно попробовать определить алгоритм так:

```
procedure MainForm.TableCalcField (DataSet : TDataset);
var
  PrevValue: Variant;
begin
  PrevValue := DataSet.Lookup('id', DataSet.FieldByName('id').AsInteger - 1, 'Field1');
  if not VarIsNull(PrevValue) then
    DataSet.FieldByName('FieldCalc').Value := DataSet.FieldByName('Field1').Value - VarAsType(PrevValue, varInteger {varDouble})
  else
    DataSet.FieldByName('FieldCalc').Value := 0;
end;
```